# How to send text area content to next page via post method?

Tags: php

I got a textarea that has some html code in it. I want to send the content of this textarea without any change to next page via post method.

```
<html>
<form id="myform" name="myform" action="./getdata.php" method="post">

<td><textarea rows="7" cols="15" name="outputtext" style="width: 99%;"></textarea></td>

<input type="submit">

</form>
</html>
```

and my php code :

```
<?
$file_contents = $_POST['outputtext'];
?>
<textarea rows="30" cols="150"><?PHP  print_r($file_contents); ?></textarea>
```

The problem with my code is that the orginal content of my first textarea gets changed when it sends to next page! For example:

```
<a href="/season/episodes.php?name=ok&id=1">
```

becomes:

```
<a href=\"/season/episodes.php?name=ok&id=1\">
```

could you guys how i can preserve the original html content without it changes in next page ?(Note all my html content changes in second pages which i dont want to change).My second textarea in second page is for testing purpose and i actually want to parse orginal value of $file_contents but for some reason it changes!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php

Comment: This sounds like magic quotes is enabled.  Please check here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have no control over php.ini its not my own server and i cant change it. Is there away to preserve the html content in second page without editing php.ini?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second PHP script, simply use strip_slashes to remove the extra slashes in the passed text:

```
<?
$file_contents = stripslashes($_POST['outputtext']);
?>
<textarea rows="30" cols="150"><?PHP  print_r($file_contents); ?></textarea>
```